# Terminating Uncaught Exception NSException - After Connecting to Server

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I've seen similar questions to this, but this error doesn't come up because of missing outlets (yellow warnings)

I go to my thank you page using the following code - and it works from everywhere

```
let login = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewThankyou")
                self.presentViewController(login!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem is that when I send info to a php file on my server, the app crashes if i try to use the above code when the php file responds.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
```

The response works without presentViewController and presentViewController works if I don't use it in the response.
I DID set the storyboard ID "ViewThankyou" and it works from everywhere except after connecting to my php file.

Comment: What are the details of the exception message?  Which line does it crash on?  If you are presenting a view controller from the result of a network operation, are you dispatching this on the main queue?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's documentation:

> After you create the task, you must start it by calling its `resume` method.

Also, try using `- dataTaskWithRequest(_, completionHandler:)`: it has an error handler within its completion handler.